# javascript/jQuery prevent form submission when not actually using a javascript/jQuery submit function

Tags: jquery, forms, form-submit

I have a PHP page which is submitting to itself using `<form action="" method="post">`. I have some jQuery field validation going on, and want to prevent the form from submitting if the validation does not pass. However, it continues to submit even when the validation doesn't pass.

What am I missing? Do I need to actually use a button (rather than submit) with a jQuery `.submit()` function in order to prevent submission? (Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fFE4K/))

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <label for="email">Username: <br />
    <input id="email" name="email" class="phPasswordTxtInputField" type="text" size="33" value=""><br />

    <label for="tmp_password">Temp password:<br />
    <input id="tmp_password" name="tmp_password" type="password"  minlength="5" value="" default="" size="33" caption=""><br />

    <label for="new_password">New password:<br />
    <input id="new_password" name="new_password" type="password"  minlength="5" value="" default="" size="33" caption=""><br />

    <label for="verify_password">Confirm password:<br />
    <input id="verify_password" name="verify_password" type="password"  minlength="5" value="" default="" size="33" caption=""><br />

    <div style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 160px;" id="lblConfirmPasswordMessage"></div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit_password" value="Reset Password" />
</form>

<script>
    function checkPasswordVerify(p,c,objId) {
        if(p != c) {
            var el =  $(objId);
            $(objId).html('<span class="passwordStrength">Please make sure the password and confirmation match.</span>');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    $('#submit_password').click(function() {
        checkPasswordVerify($(this).val(), $('#new_password').val(), '#lblConfirmPasswordMessage');
    });  
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `return` statement in your click handler:

```
$('#submit_password').click(function() {
    return checkPasswordVerify($(this).val(), $('#new_password').val(), '#lblConfirmPasswordMessage');
});
```

Also, it would be better to do this in the form's `submit` handler, not the submit button's `click` handler. Forms can be submitted without clicking on the submit button.

Comment: Ack. I knew it was something simple like that. Thanks.

Comment: Don't fret, you're not the first, you won't be the last.

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually *doing* anything with the return value of `checkPasswordVerify`.  You probably want something more like:

```
$('#submit_password').click(function() {
    return checkPasswordVerify($(this).val(), $('#new_password').val(), '#lblConfirmPasswordMessage');
});
```

Or:

```
$('#submit_password').click(function(e) {
    if(!checkPasswordVerify($(this).val(), $('#new_password').val(), '#lblConfirmPasswordMessage'))
       e.preventDefault();
});
```